# Write DF to existing Excel file with pandas and openxlpy

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a df to an existing work sheet. Initially the programme opens a dialog box to select a new sheet name to be added, then find the path of the excel sheet.

```
#reload window to select new sheet name
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x200+350+150')
root.configure(bg='#072462')

#set buttons
label_date = Label(root, text='Input New Sheet Name', bg='#072462', fg='white')
ws_new_title = Entry(root, width=45, bg='#0A1944', fg='white', highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
ws_new_title.insert(0, 'YYYY-MM-DD') #insert guide text in box
button_ws_name = Button(root, width=20, text='Select Export Excel File', command=root.quit)
button_ws_name.configure(fg='#C51E42', bg='#06122f', borderwidth=5)

label_date.pack()
ws_new_title.pack()
button_ws_name.pack(pady=30)
root.mainloop()
```

Code for dialog box to find excel path (working)

```
#find and save to new excel sheet based on a input of name
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Great Britain Basketball')
root.withdraw()
file_path_export = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Desktop/', title='Select Player Tracking document')
root.update()
export_fn = file_path_export
```

code to open workbook and add new sheet (think this. might be wrong)

```
book = load_workbook(export_fn)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(export_fn, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
```

finally to write df (full_append) to excel

```
full_append.to_excel(writer, startrow=len(df)+1, index=False, header=False, sheet_name='Season Data') #working -write to exsisting sheet and append to bottom row
full_append.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=ws_new_title, index=False) #not working - write to same sheet but on seperate sheet taking name from input
writer.save()
```

So the main issue is the programme is not adding a new sheet in the workbook using a prescribed sheet name (ws_new_title variable), and writing the df to it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the syntax error. After setting the entry button

```
ws_new_title = Entry(root, width=45, bg='#0A1944', fg='white', highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
```

I needed to change this entry to a string variable before using as a new sheet name in existing Excel sheet. To do this I used a .get() function

```
#change entry to a string
ws_name = ws_new_title.get()
```

Then finally append df to 'Season Data' and save to a new sheet based on date

```
#write to excel workbook
book = load_workbook(export_fn)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(export_fn, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

full_data_table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=ws_name, index=False) #working but need to update name based on input
full_data_table.to_excel(writer, startrow=len(df)+1, index=False, header=False, sheet_name='Season Data') #working -write to exsisting sheet and append to bottom row

writer.save()
writer.close()
```